# Limit loading of a script on PartialView MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to load SignalR scripts on my partial view for only one time, and when I make another call to this partial view with different data inside it I don't want to load those scripts that already has been loaded.

I know its bad idea to load scripts on PartialView but this is my need, kindly help me how I can do that.

Comment: Don't put scripts in partial views! Why do you think you need this?

Comment: yes its bad approach, I am not able to resolve my issue, that's why I thought may be that will be a solution.

Comment: actually I have posted this question as well waiting to resolve that issue,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262155/scripts-not-working-on-partial-view-after-ajax-call

Comment: Have just seen your last question - you need event delegation

Comment: kindly can you elaborate little more I am new to MVC and SignalR things.

Comment: See the comment on the other question (and read the link)

Comment: Microsoft has actually spent a decent amount of time and money so that we can have "includes" in our partial views. @StephenMuecke, why would you suggest otherwise? I have included scripts in many of my partial views and it had zero effect on the loading performance.

Comment: If you want to adopt bad practice then go right ahead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everybody say its a bad practice to add scripts in Partial View, But
>   some scenarios do require us to add scripts in partial view for better
>   performance.

Assuming you really want to get it this way here is my idea.

In your partial view don't include a `<script>` tag to load the scripts but use a jquery **[$.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)** to load the script. Also once the script is loaded have a flag set so that next time you just check this flag and decide if you have to load the script or not.

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("SignalRLoaded")){ // check if script is loaded
   $.getScript( "SingnalRSCripts.js",function(){
       localStorage.setItem("SignalRLoaded", true); //loaded once set flag
    });
 }
```