# Css class applied, but not the style

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In the index.cshtml I display the todo items with partial view:

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
  @foreach (var todo in Model.Todos)
  {
     <tr id="@todo.TodoId">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_TodoModel", todo);}
     </tr>
  }
```

The partial view:

```
<td class="col-md-1">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Complete, new { @class = "bigCheckbox", id = "completedFlag"+Model.TodoId })</td>
<td class="col-md-9">
   <span class="@(Model.Complete ? "completed" : "notCompleted")">
      @Model.TodoText
   </span>
</td>
<td class="col-md-2  text-center">
   @Html.ActionLink("Remove Todo", "Remove", "Todo", new { todoId = Model.TodoId }, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-danger" })
</td>
```

When the checkbox is checked the javascript is calling the controller and updating the completed flag, then redirecting to Index page again. The reload happens, the new css class applied to the element, but the style remains the old one.
Even on soft refresh the new style is applied.

I can change the style with javascript, just curious about why is above behaviour?
Also I feel a bit cleaner if the model changes the style should also change.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure no other class has taken priority?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it and no other class taking over. The appropriate class has been applied but the style not for the class...

Comment: The solution is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262155/scripts-not-working-on-partial-view-after-ajax-call